# Angular array change detection issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

I am working on a notification component in which I have an array of "error" objects and iterate through them using `*ngFor`. My issue is that Angular won't pick up the changes to the array when I mutate it inside a subscription.

My code is the following:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select().pipe(
      map(state => state.error),
      filter(error => !!error),
      map(error => ({text: error, display: 'block'}))
    ).subscribe(error => {

      // this does not get detected
      this.errors.push(error);

      setTimeout(() => {
        error.display = 'none';
      }, 4000)
    });

    // this gets detected
    this.errors.push({
      text: 'asd',
      display: 'block'
    })
  }
```

And the related html:

```html
      <div class="notification-wrapper">
          <div *ngFor="let error of errors" [style.display]="error.display" class="notification is-danger has-text-right">
              {{ error.text }}
          </div>
      </div>
```

The weird thing is that if I replace the subscription with a `setInterval` in which I constantly add dummy errors, the changes are caught by Angular and it behaves normally.

Can someone explain to me why it works this way, and maybe how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: where do you display your errors can you share the html please?

Comment: Are you with the OnPush strategy ?

Comment: @Wandrille No, the default one

Comment: How do you send those errors? Are you sure that your subscription is executed inside Angular zone?

Comment: @yurzui I have a service that holds a BehaviourSubject which gets returned as an Observable via the select method. I'm not sure what "Angular zone" means, but the code inside the subscription gets executed, I checked.

Comment: Try putting this log `console.log(window['Zone'].current.name);` inside your subscription. What will it print?

Comment: @yurzui It prints `<root>`

Comment: It means that you moved from Angular zone somewhere. You should be using `zone.run` then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201751/discussion-between-paul-cosma-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code is executed outside of Angular zone.
You can force to run it inside:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

...

this.store.select().pipe(
  map(state => state.error),
  filter(error => !!error),
  map(error => ({text: error, display: 'block'}))
).subscribe(error => {

  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.errors.push(error);

    setTimeout(() => {
      error.display = 'none';
    }, 4000)
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't do this, use observables with the async pipe.